# Compiling issues with check and autotools

Tags: automake, check-framework

I have some C unit tests with `check` framework.

My `Makefile.am` looks like:

```
check_PROGRAMS = check_fseqs
check_fseqs_SOURCES = tests/check_fseqs.c
check_fseqs_LDADD = -lcheck
```

File structure is (some files were *omitted*):

```
.
|-- Makefile.am
|-- configure.ac
|-- src
|   |-- fseqs.c
|   |-- fseqs.h
|   |-- fseqs.o
`-- tests
    `-- check_fseqs.c
```

Then I run `make check` and it throws:

```
$ make check
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  check_fseqs
gcc  -g -O2   -o check_fseqs tests/check_fseqs.o -lcheck 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_f_msb", referenced from:
      _test_f_msb in check_fseqs.o
  "_min", referenced from:
      _test_min in check_fseqs.o
  "_substract", referenced from:
      _test_substract in check_fseqs.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [check_fseqs] Error 1
make: *** [check-am] Error 2
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a dependency. If you're building fseqs.o, you need to add it as `check_DEPENDENCIES` and also add it to your `check_LDADD` line. If it was a library, you'd do the same thing, specifying the library file instead of all of the object files making the library up.

The `check_DEPENDENCIES` bit ensures the correct rule is generated, and the `check_LDADD` ensures the file is added to the command line while linking.

Comment: Thank you, I have added `src/counter_lab.o` and `src/fseqs.o` files to `check_counter_lab_LDADD` and `check_fseqs_LDADD`.

    check_counter_lab_LDADD = -lcheck src/counter_lab.o
    check_fseqs_LDADD = -lcheck src/fseqs.o